# Recursion? Combinations in a String

Tags: java, string, recursion, dynamic-programming

I've been dealing with the following recursion question for a while now and haven't been able to figure it out. Basically, you have some sort of a sentence  made out of certain words, where all the words are just jammed together, not spaced out. The idea is to find the number of all possible combinations of words that can be used to create the sentence.

For example,

- Words:    ook, ookook
- Sentence: ookookook
- Solution: {ook, ook, ook}, {ookook, ook}, {ook, ookook}.

Another example:

- Words:    ooga, oogam, oogum, mook, ook
- Sentence: oogamookoogumook
- Solution: {ooga, mook, oogum, ook}, {oogam, ook, oogum, ook}

I've tried a lot of things, finally giving up and trying to do it manually...

```
public static int WAYS(String word) {
    int ways = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        try{
            if(word.substring(i, i - 2).equals("ug")){
                if(word.substring(i - 4, i - 2).equals("ug")){
                    ways++;
                }
            }
            else if(word.substring(i, i - 3).contains("ook")){
                System.out.println(word.substring(i-6, i-3));
                if(word.substring(i - 6, i - 3).equals("ook")){
                    ways++;
                }
                if(word.charAt(i - 4) == 'm'){
                    if(word.substring(i - 8, i - 4).equals("ooga") || word.substring(i - 8, i - 4).equals("oogu")){
                        ways++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(word.substring(i, i - 4).contains("mook")){
                if(word.substring(i - 8, i - 4).contains("mook")){
                    ways++;
                }
            }
            if(word.substring(i, i - 2).equals("oog")){
                if(word.charAt(i + 2) == 'm'){
                    if(word.charAt(i + 1) == 'a' || word.charAt(i + 1) == 'u'){
                        ways++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            continue;
        }
    }
    return ways;
}
```

But it hasn't worked. Could somebody please give me an idea or a sample on approaching this problem using recursion?

Comment: Can you show your recursive attempt? You really, really need to use recursion on this problem. A non-recursive solution like what you posted is just not going to work.

Comment: @JohnKugelman  my recursive attempts were really awful since I can't understand how to properly solve this question with recursion. I just need to understand the basics on how to approach these types of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Name your methods properly, "WAYS" is a constant name, not a method name.
2. Provide runnable code, especially in cases where it's so short.
3. Never use Exceptions for control flow. *(*Never say never; But unless you're actually designing some weird control flow primitives, like support for non-local returns: don't use Exceptions for control flow)*
4. You are using magic values like "uug" and "ook" in your code? Does this look simple and obvious? Does this look maintainable? What is this supposed to look like if you get a lexicon with a million of different words?

Edit: giving the complete listing is somehow boring, so I left a few gaps. Try to fill those, hope that helps.

```
public class JammedWords {
  public static int ways(String sentence, String[] words) {
    if (sentence.isEmpty()) {
      // The trivial case: the sentence is empty. Return a single number.
    } else {
      int c = 0;
      for (String w: words) {
        if (sentence.startsWith(w)) {
          // call method recursively, update counter `c`.
        }
      }
      return c;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ways("ookookook", new String[]{"ook", "ookook"}));
    System.out.println(ways("oogamookoogumook", new String[]{"ooga","oogam","oogum","mook","ook"}));
  }
}
```

Hints:

A) Understand the difference between empty set, set containing the empty set, set containing a set containing an empty set etc. Sets that contain empty sets are of course not empty, and their size is not 0.

B) There is a handy method String.substring(n) that drops everything before the 'n'-th character. And there is String.length() to get size of words.

Answer (score 1):

Hope VB.NET code won't mind, just for the grasp.

```
Private Sub Go()
    Dim words As New List(Of String)

    words.Add("ooga")
    words.Add("oogam")
    words.Add("oogum")
    words.Add("mook")
    words.Add("ook")

    Search("oogamookoogumook", words, "", New List(Of String))
End Sub

Private Sub Search(ByVal sentence As String, _
                        ByVal wordList As List(Of String), _
                        ByVal actualSentenceBuildingState As String, _
                        ByVal currentPath As List(Of String))

    For Each word As String In wordList
        Dim actualSentenceAttemp As String
        Dim thisPath As New List(Of String)(currentPath)

        thisPath.Add(word)
        actualSentenceAttemp = actualSentenceBuildingState + word

        If actualSentenceAttemp = sentence Then
            Debug.Print("Found: " + String.Join("->", thisPath.ToArray()))
        End If

        If actualSentenceAttemp.Length < sentence.Length Then 'if we are not too far, we can continue
            Search(sentence, wordList, actualSentenceAttemp, thisPath)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Printouts:

```
Sentence: oogamookoogumook
Found: ooga->mook->oogum->ook
Found: oogam->ook->oogum->ook

Sentence: ookookook
Found: ook->ook->ook
Found: ook->ookook
Found: ookook->ook
```

Think about it as walking in graph (its nothing else than that in fact). You start with nothing (empty string). Now you start to iteratively add words from wordlist into your 'current attemp for sentence'. After adding word to current attemp, you can end only in three possible states: (1) you got the final sentence, (2) current attemp is shorter than target sentence and thus still suitable for adding next words (recursion call), or (3), your current attemp is longer (or the same length but not equal) than target sequence, thus it has no meaning to continue in search with it.

What you have to remember is path -- "how did i get here?" list (back tracking).